# VBA - ADO stored procedure with Output parameters

Tags: vba

I am unable to execute stored procedure from VBA. The stored procedure has 1 input parameter which is the job name and returns an output value. Error is at execute line.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Run_SQL_Job_Test]  
    @vJobName VARCHAR(50),
    @vJobStatus INTEGER OUTPUT 
AS
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @vJobname 
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

   IF @vJobName = 'JOBName-Test' 
   BEGIN
       PRINT 'Inside New Code'

       SELECT @vJobStatus = run_status 
       FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
       WHERE instance_id = (SELECT MAX(instance_id) 
                            FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory 
                            WHERE step_name = 'JOBName-Test')
  END
```

VBA code:

```
Public cnn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public cmd As ADODB.Command
Public pm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim vJobStatus As Integer

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnnStr = ""
cnnStr = "PROVIDER=XXXXX;DATA SOURCE=XXXX;INITIAL CATALOG=XXXX;INTEGRATED SECURITY=XXX"
cnn.Open cnnStr

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set pm = New ADODB.Parameter
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "Run_SQL_Job_Test"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120

cmd.Parameters.Refresh
Set pm = cmd.CreateParameter("@vJobName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "JOBName-Test")
cmd.Parameters.Append pm          
Set pm = cmd.CreateParameter("@vJobStatus", adInteger, adParamOutput, , vJobStatus)
cmd.Parameters.Append pm
cmd.Execute
vJobStatus = cmd.Parameters("@vJobStatus")
```

Comment: What is the error code/description?

Comment: I think you use the wrong SP-Name for `CommandText` - it should be "Run_SQL_Job_Test"

Comment: I used the correct proc name but still I am getting the error

Comment: This is related to access issue. I got access to execute stored proc and it is resolved now.

Comment: You forgot the most critical part when displaying value from output parameter. You need to close the recordset to get the value from output paremeters. After the cmd.Execute, Please add rs.close, then vJobStatus = cmd.Parameters("@vJobStatus")